# add text instead of numbers in pagination, angular-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am using angular-bootstrap for pagination and want to change page number with text like year(eg. 2015, 2014, 2013).
Can we customize angular pagination directive so that achieve that case?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/csots4OSB8UP8TkSwfqc?p=preview

Comment: This requirement had been addressed in [angular-ui/bootstrap issue 2532](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2532) and see [PR 2705](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2705)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own directive on base of the 'pagination' directive and just modify the getPages function. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/se6ovp8DPiyhKGfsSwVu?p=preview)

```
    // Add page number links
    for (var number = startPage; number <= endPage; number++) {
      var text = parseInt(scope.startYear, 10) + (number - 1);
      var page = makePage(number, text, number === currentPage);
      pages.push(page);
    }
```

Comment: it will provide a new attribute `pageLabel` if [angular-ui/bootstrap/2705](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2705) gets merged

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the source, it does not appear that there is any way to configure the text for page number buttons currently.

Answer (score 0):

By using the page-label attribute

html

```
 <ul uib-pagination page-label="pageLable($page)"></ul>
```

js

```
 $scope.pageLable = function($page){
     return 2000 + $page;
 }
```

check this example: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/4ju8OuYdJGsUC6vahmr1?p=preview